# Jenkins Jenkinsfile Groovy bash command no such file or directory

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The file validates and I look to have the proper syntax.

```
          script {
          sh """
          summon -f folder/file.yml --provider summon-aws-secrets \
          sh -c 'bash folder/bin/run_me.sh' \
          """


          open folder/file.yml: no such file or directory
```

I confirmed the existence of the file and workspace location.

Answer (score 0):

Try using full path with workspace variable:

```
script {
          sh """
          summon -f ${WORKSPACE}/folder/file.yml --provider summon-aws-secrets \
          sh -c 'bash folder/bin/run_me.sh' \
          """
}
```

Comment: summon -f /var/jenkins/workspace/folder_develop/folder/file.yml --provider summon-aws- 
     secrets sh -c bash /var/jenkins/workspace/folder_develop/folder/bin/run_me.sh
     open /var/jenkins/workspace/folder_develop/folder/file.yml: no such file or directory
     [Pipeline] }

Comment: Now, I'm curious... Can you try to add before your step: sh "ls -l ${WORKSPACE} && ls -l ${WORKSPACE}/folder/ && ls -l ${WORKSPACE}/folder/file.yml" to make sure that it is there

Comment: `+ ls -l /var/jenkins/workspace/folder_develop
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 2329 Apr 27 13:06 Jenkinsfile.gvy

+ ls -l /var/jenkins/workspace/folder_develop/folder/
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 2958 Apr 27 13:06 script.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Apr 27 13:06 bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins   53 Apr 27 13:06 requirements.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins   52 Apr 27 13:06 file.yml

+ ls -l /var/jenkins/workspace/folder_develop/folder/file.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 52 Apr 27 13:06 /var/jenkins/workspace/folder_develop/folder/file.yml `

Comment: I ran a 2nd test where I created a summon.sh to wrap the command line tool into a bash script. I added the file, commited, and pushed. When I ran the ls-l job in jenkins the file is not there. So at this point Im baffled at the jenkins behavior

Answer (score 0):

so what I see happening is I wrapped the file into a script. ran git add , git commit, git push. I updated the jenkins file to ls -l the folder and I notice that file is missing. so not sure if this is a git issue or jenkins or etc